# linq to xml access data based on field attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have some xml like this:

```
  <Data>
      <Rows>
        <Row>
          <Field Name="title">Mr</Field>
          <Field Name="surname">Doe</Field>
        <Row>
      <Rows>
 <Data>
```

using linq how can I get the value contained in the field element where the attribute is surname

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can express your query using LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<Data><Rows><Row><Field Name=\"title\">Mr</Field><Field Name=\"surname\">Doe</Field></Row></Rows></Data>");
string[] matches = (from e in doc.Descendants("Field")
                    where (string)e.Attribute("Name") == "surname"
                    select (string)e).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're trying to do an XML-to-Linq thing here. Linq to XML is more meant to create an XML structure from objects through Linq.

Since you have an XML file, you can use something like this:

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(Content);
        string Surname = xml.SelectSingleNode("//Field/[@Name='surname']").Value.ToString();
```

In other use, to get data from XML, use XPath instead.

Comment: I believe LINQ to XML is very much intended to be an alternative to XPath, offering strongly-typed support and a more intuitive query syntax.

Comment: LINQ to XML adds another layer on top of the XML. Basically, what it does is translate your query to XPath constructions. Looking at the XQuery sample from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb330936.aspx you can see how you can write a complex query in LINQ instead of XPath. LINQ is more intuitive for those who aren't experienced with XPath. That's true.